# WinError 5 access is denied - renaming files - Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have been trying to create an executable for a simple file name converter.
the goal is to rename all files from a certain directory to their creation date (for images).

```py
import datetime
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
    
path = askdirectory(title='Select Folder')  # shows dialog box and return the path
os.chdir(path)
files = os.listdir(path)
for filename in files:
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))
    os.rename(filename, time_stamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S') + ".jpg")
```

It works perfectly where I run it through PyCharm, but when I run it through the executable that I created using pyInstaller, I get "[WinError 5] access is denied". The premission error occures because of the `os.rename()` function.

I tried to run it as an administrator but I got the same result.
I also updated my python, pycharm and pip but that had no effect.

Is there a way to make this script an executable?

thank you all

Comment: Pycharm is run in a venv while .exe files aren't, try running as administrator (right click on file, run as administrator)

Comment: already did that as I mentioned.. is there any other solution?

Comment: Sorry must have missed that part

Comment: Have you checked if your anti-virus software is stopping it

Comment: Thank you that actually worked! is there something I can put on the script or while generating the .exe file that will let it work despite of the antivirus?

Comment: I'm not sure since antivirus is usually 3rd party it is unlikely that there is a script for it but you could always do a google search or tell the anti-virus to ignore certain files if it can